# Is my code wrong, or there is a bug in opencart

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, opencart

I've created extremely simple module for Opencart, just displaying hello world in the admin panel. Here is my controller:

```
<?php

class ControllerExtensionModuleHelloworld extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->language('/extension/module/helloworld');
        $this->document->setTitle('Hello World');
        
        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
        $data['helloworld'] = $this->language->get('helloworld');
        
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/helloworld', $data));
    }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
{{header}}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col">
        {{column_left}}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h1>{{heading_title}}</h1>
            <p>{{helloworld}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{footer}}
```

The problem is that the h1 and the p tags are displayed under the the column-left like this:[image: problem]
I changed the col classes with col-sm-4 and col-sm-8 like this:

```
{{header}}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        {{column_left}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h1>{{heading_title}}</h1>
            <p>{{helloworld}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{footer}}
```

But this didn't work, finally I added  col-sm-offset-2 class to the col-sm-8 div, and it shifted the text left, like it's suppose to be.
Any ideas where the problem may be?

Comment: Note that you have an unclosed quote in `<div class="row>`.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the mistake, however this didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ header }} {{column_left}}
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1>{{ heading_title }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- content here -->
  </div>
</div>
{{ footer }}
```

Try this, it should work.